# SQL query alignment change when Arabic characters are inserted

Tags: sql, arabic, msde

I have a query like this

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
SET DATEFORMAT 'mdy' 

INSERT INTO TABLE1 
  (AccountID, TimeStamp, UserID, NodeID, Deleted, UserPriority,  ParentRecordID, NodeLevel, Name, NodeClass, DeviceID, DeviceType, SubTypeLevel)  
VALUES 
  (0, "10/03/2002 02:33:39", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,"XXXXXX",7000, 0, 0, 0`)
```

When I replace XXXXXX with منطقة تحكم بالبداية السريعة, the query after the string turns right to left like this

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
SET DATEFORMAT 'mdy' 

INSERT INTO TABLE1 
  (AccountID, TimeStamp, UserID, NodeID, Deleted, UserPriority,  ParentRecordID, NodeLevel, Name, NodeClass, DeviceID, DeviceType, SubTypeLevel)  
VALUES 
  (0, "10/03/2002 02:33:39", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "منطقة تحكم بالبداية السريعة", 7000, 0, 0, 0)
```

Please tell me how to overcome this.

I am using SQL server 2000 MSDE.

Comment: are you building the query in T-SQL or in some application?

Comment: is this the way your query is actually formatted, or are the commands on separate lines?

Comment: There's a lot of typos, and shouldn't the double quotes really be single quotes?

Comment: The problem exists if I use this query with Arabic characters. Even the string is not inserted properly in the database. Instead, ????? is inserted. If I use CRecordset/VC++ to insert values, the string is inserted properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved when we add N before the nvarchar value.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF SET DATEFORMAT 'mdy' INSERT INTO ControlTreeEx (AccountID, TimeStamp, UserID, NodeID, Deleted, UserPriority,  ParentRecordID, NodeLevel, Name, NodeClass, DeviceID, DeviceType, SubTypeLevel)  VALUES (0, "10/03/2002 02:33:39", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, N'منطقة تحكم بالبداية', 7000, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this case by adding the **letter N before** each values entered (that need conversion)

For example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(AccountID, TimeStamp, UserID, NodeID, Deleted, UserPriority, 
       ParentRecordID, NodeLevel, Name, NodeClass, DeviceID, DeviceType, SubTypeLevel)  
VALUES 
  (0, "10/03/2002 02:33:39", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "منطقة تحكم بالبداية السريعة"N, 7000, 0, 0, 0)
```

=>

```
Insert ... Into ... Values (id1,id2,..., N'Arabic word',N'Hebrew word',N'Chinese word');
```